# collapsed menu - hide other submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to a create collapsed navbar. I have problem that I have errors when I try hide expanded items. It's for cms and I cannot use ids, I have to close it by class.
I had the idea to close it during `show` event, but it throws an error.

I have tried something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
            $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
        });
    });
```

but I have the error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /(^|\.)bs\.(?:.*\.|)collapse(\.|$)
```

I need it to work similar to a dropdown menu, if you click on one, it will be open, if click on another, then first is hidden and only 1 is active in one time.

HTML:

```
`<div class="nav navbar-nav">
    <ul>
    <li>
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="Divs ids" class="collapsed">name</a>
    </li>
</ul>`


`<div id="subcategories">
    <div id="20" class="collapse" >.... </div>
    <div id="21" class="collapse" >.... </div>
    <div id="22" class="collapse" >.... </div>
</div>`
```

edit:
i resovled my problem
another selector in method works perfectly

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e){
            $(".collapse[aria-expanded='true']").collapse("hide");
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide an example and some more context?

Comment: Please show the HTML.

Comment: Where are you using your regex `/(^|\.)bs\.(?:.*\.|)collapse(\.|$)` ?

Comment: Can offer more help if you provide the HTML.

Comment: `<div class="nav navbar-nav">
<ul>
<li>
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="Divs ids" class="collapsed">name</a>

....
<div id="subcategories">
<div id="20" class collapse" >.... </div>
<div id="21" class collapse" >.... </div>
<div id="22" class collapse" >.... </div>
</div>`

code looks like this, <a> tags collapse/expand proper div

Comment: `class collapse"` do you see anything missing here?

Comment: html code was as example, it works on my page. problem is when i try invoke 
    $(".collapse").collapse("hide");

in function which handle event "show.bs.collapse", if i invoke in from console, everything work fine instead first call, which at first expand not expanded divs

Comment: what is `data-target="Divs ids"` ?

Comment: "divs ids" means that there are few elements in lists and each element coresspond to proper div from subcategories:
http://oi64.tinypic.com/evdfs2.jpg
i have got it like on picutre, but i want that if i click o Desktops, then subcategories from Laptops & notebooks should hide, now i have choosen 2 subcategories

Answer (score 0):

`'show.bs.collapse'` hmm try using `'shown.bs.collapse'` with an `n`.

And here's the jQuery and stuff:

```js
var $subCat = $('#subcategories');

$subCat.on("shown.bs.collapse", ".collapse", function() {
   $subCat.find(".collapse").not(this).collapse("hide");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<div class="nav navbar-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#20" class="collapsed">20name</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#21" class="collapsed">21name</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#22" class="collapsed">22name</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="subcategories">
  <div id="20" class="collapse">20.... </div>
  <div id="21" class="collapse">21.... </div>
  <div id="22" class="collapse">22.... </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's better but it doesn't fix problem, it doesn't throw error but at first show expanded div and then collapse them,
Also at first click on button, it collapse clicked elements, but expand elements which weren't yet clicked, is there function which should be invoked on  items with .collapse class which activate proper bahavior ?

Comment: It's something what i want, but using "shown" makes that for 1 second are displayed two submenus,  then one is collapsed. Also i've got still problem that on first run, this method, makes that collapsed divs are expanded, in next calls it works proper, collapse one, and expand another.